# Combining Poisson estimates

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution

On average, 10 buses and 60 cars pass your house per hour.  During one period of time, you count 11 buses and 40 cars passing your house.  How long were you counting for?

My first thought is to make one estimate based on the bus count and one based on the car count.  However, the estimate based on the car count is more reliable, due to the greater number of observations.  So how to combine the two - if that is even the right way to go about it?

Comment: It may help that the [waiting time between Poisson events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Characterisation) is known to be distributed as an [exponential random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Comment: @Avraham: Thank you for your input! I will keep that fact in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use maximum likelihood.  Let $X$ be the number of buses, $Y$ be the number of cars. Then, with $\lambda$ the observation period in hours, we have $X\sim \text{Po}(10\lambda), Y\sim \text{Po}(60\lambda)$, so the likelihood function based on assuming that $X, Y$ are independent, is proportional to
$$
  L(\lambda)= e^{-70\lambda} \lambda^{x+y}
$$  (factors which do not depend on $\lambda$ can be omitted)
so the maximum likelihood estimator is 
$$
\hat{\lambda} = \frac{x+y}{70}   
$$
We can check that that gives an unbiased estimate, that is, $E \hat{\lambda}=\lambda$, below:
$$
  E \hat{\lambda} = \frac{E(X+Y)}{70}= \frac{10\lambda+60\lambda}{70}=\lambda
$$

Comment: +1. But note that the likelihood function is only proportional to $L(\lambda)$, not equal to it.

Comment: @whuber:  yes, but the likelihood function is only defined up to a multiplicative constant, so that is fine.

Comment: Yes, it's fine--but it can cause confusion when people try to check their work against yours. I made the comment to pre-empt possible frustration on that account.  It would be simple enough for you to replace "equal to" by "proportional to," or even to write down the full correct likelihood.